# Why I am not getting the lattest version of a python package when installing it with pip?

Tags: python, pip, vtk

I'd like the latest version of vtk under python 3.6

Pipy.org indicates version 9.0.0 :
[https://pypi.org/project/vtk/#files](https://pypi.org/project/vtk/)
The url instructs to use the command :

`pip install vtk`

I have both python 2.7 and 3.6 installed so I actually use :

`pip3 install vtk`

But this installs version 8.1.2, not 9.0.0

If I run the command :

`pip3 install vtk==9.0.0`

```
    Collecting vtk==9.0.0   
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk==9.0.0 (from versions:
    8.0.0.dev20170717, 8.1.0, 8.1.1, 8.1.2) No matching distribution found for vtk==9.0.0
```

The same thing happens for python2.7 and pip.
Why am I not getting the version listed at PiPy.org?

Comment: Is your pip up to date?

Comment: I did : sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip

, got python3.6/dist-packages (20.1.1), 


But I am stil getting vtk 8.1.2

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, it works fine for me. Try to install from [source](https://vtk.org/download/) instead.

Comment: The install files listed on PiPy.org for vtk ar only for windows and mac, not linux. I wonder if that's why. (I am on Ubuntu)
Anyway, yes, installing using the wheel from vtk.org works. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vtk` 8.1.2 [provides](https://pypi.org/project/vtk/8.1.2/#files) wheels for Linux, MacOS and w64.

But `vtk` 9.0.0 [provides](https://pypi.org/project/vtk/9.0.0/#files) wheels for MacOS and w64, not for Linux.

On Linux you have to use version 8.1.2. Or download a wheel from https://vtk.org/download. Or compile VTK from sources.

Answer (score 3):

VTK 9.0.1 has been released on PyPI on Jun 24, 2020, with Linux-compatible wheels this time:

```
path/to/python3 -m pip install vtk==9.0.1
```